# How to get returned data from another URL?

Tags: angular, database, redirect

I have a problem.
I have an application in which, after clicking on the link
redirects me to a separate page (not related to mine). I log in to this website and after logging in, it returns me data in the form of an HTML form. I then have to handle this data on my website. Of course, after logging in, this page will return me to my home page.
For example, I'm on my website and I have

```
 <div class="wezel-krajowy">
        <a [href]="Link">{{ "login.link" | translate }}</a>
      </div>
```

When clicked, it will redirect me to this page.
I log in there and after logging in correctly, it returns me to my web site.
I also know that it sends the data I need.

How can I extract this data so that I can handle it?

I know he will return the form to me

```
return @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""en"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<body>
    <form id=""f0"" method=""post"" action=""http://localhost:4200"" enctype=""application/x-www-form-urlencoded"">
        <input name=""SessionIndex"" value=""" + session + @""" />
        <input type=""hidden"" name=""EntityName"" value=""EkomadresTest"" />
        <noscript>
            <div>
                Script execution is disabled on this page. Click Submit to continue.
            </div>
            <div>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </form>
    <h2>Poprawnie zalogowano przez Węzeł Krajowy!</h2>
    <div>
        Indeks sesji: " + session + @"<br/>
        Identity Name: " + identityName + @"
    </div>

    <div>
        Żeby się wylogować kliknij <a href=""" + link + @""">TUTAJ.</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('f0').submit();
        }, 0);
    </script>
</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: How is the data sent? To where exactly? It's hard to understand what is happening really.

Comment: After logging in, this page (separate). Submits this form, and redirect me " <form id=""f0"" method=""post"" action=""http://localhost:4200"" enctype=""application/x-www-form-urlencoded"">" to localhost. And i need read this data

Comment: You will need server-side code to read the request that is sent.

Comment: On the side of my server or the server of that website?

Comment: On your side, the localhost:4200 is the one receiving the form data as it is defined by the form's action attribute. But port 4200 is the default port for Angular devlopment server so I think you are simply reaching your angular app. You need to create a server to receive the request, do what you want to do with it and then redirect to your angular app/

Comment: I just got from the backend guy that our API returns this form. The question is, how do I receive it on my application side?

Comment: Meh, ask the backend guy how he's sending it... Or how you should retrieve it. We cannot help without the details.